# Slide in keyframes animation not working

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations

So I implemented [this](http://css-tricks.com/slide-in-as-you-scroll-down-boxes/) animation to some similar modules in a previous mockup, and it worked fine. Today I wanted to use the same animation on another mockup, and I copied over the code as it was basically the same. I've put all the relevant code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2Le51ym/).

As you can see in the fiddle, the blocks all adhere to the transformY and move down 150px (if they're scrolled into view), but they don't animate back up as per the come-in animation:

```
@keyframes come-in {
to {
transform: translateY(0); } }
```

Although it was working fine when I used it before, it seems like it somehow stopped working in my previous mockup now in the same way, although I'm pretty sure I didn't do anything to it. The appropriate classes are definitely applying, so it seems like the jQuery is working, it just seems like something is wrong with this specific keyframes animation.

Any ideas? Am I missing something incredibly obvious? Thanks!

Comment: Confused! The jsFiddle seems to work just fine--does the same thing that CSS Tricks shows. What's not working??

Comment: Hm, it's definitely not working for me. Really weird! Maybe just something with my browser/computer? I don't have any updates... I'll restart and see what happens.

Comment: So it's still not working for me. If it helps, I'm in Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: Agh, okay, just had to add webkit prefixes. Silly me. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it was something rather obvious. It turned out to just not be working in Chrome, so I added prefixes.

```
.come-in {
transform: translateY(150px);
  animation: come-in 0.2s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation: come-in 0.2s ease forwards;}

@-webkit-keyframes come-in {
to {
    transform: translateY(0); } }
```

What kills me is that it didn't seem to need the prefixes for some reason only a few weeks ago!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. :) Could you accept your answer so that this question is closed, please? Thank you!

Comment: It says I only can tomorrow. I will then.